# PHP Simple Array Mystery Null Value

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, null

I have an array of hex color codes and want to loop through them and compare to a database entry. Here is the code:

```
// database connect & query hidden for brevity

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$colors =  array("EEEEEE","EEEED8","EEEEAA","EEEE9A","EEEE77","EEEE49","EEEE21","EEEE00",
                 "DAFFFF","DAFFF3","DAFFDA","DAFFD2","DAFFBF","DAFFA6","DAFF91","DAFF7F",
                 "9FFFFF","9FFFED","9FFFC8","9FFFBB","9FFF9F","9FFF7A","9FFF5A","9FFF3F",
                 "19FFFF","19FFEA","19FFBD","19FFAE","19FF8C","19FF60","19FF39","19FF19",
                 "BBC8FF","9FC8FF","7AC8FF","5AC8FF","3FC8FF","7A7AFF","5A7AFF","3F7AFF",
                 "BB7AFF","9F7AFF","608CFF","398CFF","198CFF","6039FF","3939FF","1939FF",
                 "EEAAAA","EEAAEE","EEAAD8","FF91D2","C87AFF","8C39FF","BD39FF","AE39FF",
                 "EEAA77","EEAA49","EEAA21","EEAA00","FF5A3F","FF6039","FF6019","FF3919",
                 "FF5A9F","FF5A7A","FF5A5A","FF6060","FF3960","FF3F5A","FF3F3F","FF3939");


if(!in_array($row['color1'],$colors))
{
    $colors[] = $row['color1'];
}
if(!in_array($row['color2'],$colors))
{
    $colors[] = $row['color2'];
}

$count = count($colors);

echo "The Database says Color1 is: ".$row['color1']."<br>";
echo "The Colors Array says it is: ".$colors[73]."<br><br>";
echo "The Database says Color2 is: ".$row['color2']."<br>";
echo "The Colors Array says it is: ".$colors[74]."<br><br><br>";

echo "Going Through the Loops shows:<br><br>";

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    if(('#'.$colors[$i]) == $row['color1'])
        echo 'FOUND IT!!! ----&gt; '.$colors[$i].'<br>';
    else
        echo 'Nope, not this one... '.$colors[$i].'<br>';
}

echo "&lt;br&gt;And Printing the Array we see:<br><br><br>";
print_r($colors);
```

The problem is the second to last iteration through the loop prints a null and the last color is lost entirely. I've tried this several different ways and all result in the same.

Here is the output:

```
The Database says Color1 is: 51A800
The Colors Array says it is: 51A800

The Database says Color2 is: 8FC400
The Colors Array says it is: 8FC400

Going Through the Loops shows:

Nope, not this one... EEEEEE
Nope, not this one... EEEED8
Nope, not this one... EEEEAA
Nope, not this one... EEEE9A
Nope, not this one... EEEE77
Nope, not this one... EEEE49
Nope, not this one... EEEE21
Nope, not this one... EEEE00
Nope, not this one... DAFFFF
Nope, not this one... DAFFF3
Nope, not this one... DAFFDA
Nope, not this one... DAFFD2
Nope, not this one... DAFFBF
Nope, not this one... DAFFA6
Nope, not this one... DAFF91
Nope, not this one... DAFF7F
Nope, not this one... 9FFFFF
Nope, not this one... 9FFFED
Nope, not this one... 9FFFC8
Nope, not this one... 9FFFBB
Nope, not this one... 9FFF9F
Nope, not this one... 9FFF7A
Nope, not this one... 9FFF5A
Nope, not this one... 9FFF3F
Nope, not this one... 19FFFF
Nope, not this one... 19FFEA
Nope, not this one... 19FFBD
Nope, not this one... 19FFAE
Nope, not this one... 19FF8C
Nope, not this one... 19FF60
Nope, not this one... 19FF39
Nope, not this one... 19FF19
Nope, not this one... BBC8FF
Nope, not this one... 9FC8FF
Nope, not this one... 7AC8FF
Nope, not this one... 5AC8FF
Nope, not this one... 3FC8FF
Nope, not this one... 7A7AFF
Nope, not this one... 5A7AFF
Nope, not this one... 3F7AFF
Nope, not this one... BB7AFF
Nope, not this one... 9F7AFF
Nope, not this one... 608CFF
Nope, not this one... 398CFF
Nope, not this one... 198CFF
Nope, not this one... 6039FF
Nope, not this one... 3939FF
Nope, not this one... 1939FF
Nope, not this one... EEAAAA
Nope, not this one... EEAAEE
Nope, not this one... EEAAD8
Nope, not this one... FF91D2
Nope, not this one... C87AFF
Nope, not this one... 8C39FF
Nope, not this one... BD39FF
Nope, not this one... AE39FF
Nope, not this one... EEAA77
Nope, not this one... EEAA49
Nope, not this one... EEAA21
Nope, not this one... EEAA00
Nope, not this one... FF5A3F
Nope, not this one... FF6039
Nope, not this one... FF6019
Nope, not this one... FF3919
Nope, not this one... FF5A9F
Nope, not this one... FF5A7A
Nope, not this one... FF5A5A
Nope, not this one... FF6060
Nope, not this one... FF3960
Nope, not this one... FF3F5A
Nope, not this one... FF3F3F
Nope, not this one... FF3939
Nope, not this one... 
Nope, not this one... 51A800

And Printing the Array we see:

Array ( [0] => EEEEEE [1] => EEEED8 [2] => EEEEAA [3] => EEEE9A [4] => EEEE77 [5] => EEEE49 [6] => EEEE21 [7] => EEEE00 [8] => DAFFFF [9] => DAFFF3 [10] => DAFFDA [11] => DAFFD2 [12] => DAFFBF [13] => DAFFA6 [14] => DAFF91 [15] => DAFF7F [16] => 9FFFFF [17] => 9FFFED [18] => 9FFFC8 [19] => 9FFFBB [20] => 9FFF9F [21] => 9FFF7A [22] => 9FFF5A [23] => 9FFF3F [24] => 19FFFF [25] => 19FFEA [26] => 19FFBD [27] => 19FFAE [28] => 19FF8C [29] => 19FF60 [30] => 19FF39 [31] => 19FF19 [32] => BBC8FF [33] => 9FC8FF [34] => 7AC8FF [35] => 5AC8FF [36] => 3FC8FF [37] => 7A7AFF [38] => 5A7AFF [39] => 3F7AFF [40] => BB7AFF [41] => 9F7AFF [42] => 608CFF [43] => 398CFF [44] => 198CFF [45] => 6039FF [46] => 3939FF [47] => 1939FF [48] => EEAAAA [49] => EEAAEE [50] => EEAAD8 [51] => FF91D2 [52] => C87AFF [53] => 8C39FF [54] => BD39FF [55] => AE39FF [56] => EEAA77 [57] => EEAA49 [58] => EEAA21 [59] => EEAA00 [60] => FF5A3F [61] => FF6039 [62] => FF6019 [63] => FF3919 [64] => FF5A9F [65] => FF5A7A [66] => FF5A5A [67] => FF6060 [68] => FF3960 [69] => FF3F5A [70] => FF3F3F [71] => FF3939 [73] => 51A800 [74] => 8FC400 )
```

I've never had a problem with a simple array before... What am I not seeing? I have a terrible feeling this is one of those stupid things where it's a stupid zero-width space or something stupid like that, but I can't find it...

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but things between "" are interpreted by php, so one of the color *might* be interpreted as an hexadecimal value, an address, or whatever. Try to replace "" by '' in the array. Additionally, you can do `var_dump($colors[$i]);` in the loop

Comment: In the if-statement you prefix `$colors` with '#' which you don't have in `$row` as far as I can see. This may or may not be a problem depending on how much this corresponds to the production code.

Comment: Your missing info Mason, whats happening with the two arrays?

Comment: And to comment to the question, when printing the "Nope, not this one", I would also suggest to print the value of `$i` to identify the values.

Comment: The initial `$colors` array has indices `0` to `71`, so the next 2 should be at indices `72` and `73`, not `73` and `74`. Not sure why it's adding a blank at `72`.

Comment: What version of PHP is this? Index 72 is just plain missing from the array, so this looks like a bug in PHP to me (as the syntax is right).

Comment: As a test for what I wrote, what if you put `$colors = array_values($colors)` just before the `$count=...` statement?

Comment: definitively funky, [check this php fiddle... herrr codepad.viper i mean ^^](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6GZPc6) (everything ok)

Comment: on side note there is `if(('#'.$colors[$i]) == $row['color1'])`, but it appears both $row and $colors have the save format, without the "#", so you can delete it from the "if" `if($colors[$i] == $row['color1'])`

Comment: If you add an element at the end (new index 72), then unset it, then use empty brackets to add another element, this new element will have index 73 and the index 72 will be null. See the note under "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax" at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. Did you leave out some code between the initialization on `$colors` and the if statements that add elements?

Comment: @roselan Thanks for the suggestion on the "" vs '', I made the change, but no difference. Also thanks for pointing out the '#' in my if, I had changed that from before where I was storing the values in the array with '#' on the front of each value, forgot to change the if, nice catch!

Comment: @Fluff Thanks for pointing out the '#' in my if, forgot to take that out and that does help. It didn't solve the null problem, but still helpful. Also, good suggestion on adding $i to the prints, I did that and I noticed as others were pointing out that 72 is missing...

Comment: @TobyAllen I'm not sure what you mean, but basically I'm defining an array with strings and then adding 1 or 2 more strings to the end of the array if they are not already present. For some reason there is a mystery null. I am not taking anything out of the array at any point.

Comment: @slugonamission You may have a good point there about the bug... I'm running PHP Version 5.2.17, but as far as I can tell no one has reported a bug for this type of thing for this version.

Comment: @JohnPS indeed that makes sense, but I didn't remove or unset anything. All the code above is what I use (at least what relates in some way to this array), except I loop through the values again to create a Select element for a form.

Comment: @slugonamission I restarted my server and now it is working. I'm not sure if it was just that, some change I made as per one or more of the suggestions here, or some combination of the two, but I wanted to thank you for mentioning it possibly being a php bug as that reminded me sometimes it's just the little things (like restarting the server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
if(!in_array($row['color1'],$colors))
{
    $colors[] = $row['color1'];
}
if(!in_array($row['color2'],$colors))
{
    $colors[] = $row['color2'];
}
```

Will insert a blank entry into the colors array once if either `$row['color1']` or `$row['color2']` is blank / empty. Modify the check to something like this, which should get rid of your empty value.

```
if( !empty( $row['color1']) && !in_array($row['color1'],$colors))
{
    $colors[] = $row['color1'];
}
if( !empty( $row['color2']) &&  !in_array($row['color2'],$colors))
{
    $colors[] = $row['color2'];
}
```

**Edit:** Here is one way to replicate your loop output.

1. You have your indexes mixed up, 74 does not exist.
2. `$row['color1']` is empty, `$row['color2']` is `51A800`
3. You probably have warnings / error reporting turned off

See the demo below, it's exactly replicating the output from the loop.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/09iCRl)

### EDIT: Found the blank entry

I was wrong to think the entry is blank - It's actually **not present** in the array. Check out the array output above:

```
[71] => FF3939 [73] => 51A800 [74] => 8FC400 )
              ^^
             ????
```

If you loop based on `count( $array)`, you get `73`, which is the **correct** number of elements. You loop from `0-73`, while `72` does **NOT** exist. You never get `74` because there are only `73` elements in the array, so you never get to index `74`. Figure out why index `72` is missing / gone, and you'll solve entire problem. Perhaps the real problem lies in code that was not pasted to SO.

Running with this, [here is a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KpR254) that replicates the output (if error reporting was turned off, it would), if somewhere along the line, `72` gets erased.

Finally, [here is a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/thWwPb) that replicates the output **exactly** if some entry is inserted into the array and then removed before the `$row` colors are inserted into the `$colors` array. My best guess is that this is what is happening in some part of the OP's omitted code.

Comment: i didn't see the part where more colors were added to the array, good spotting!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that flaw in my conditionals. However, I tried it and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @mason81 - I've posted a demo that **exactly** replicates your output (the loop), which is likely what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: But he prints `$row['color1']` and $row['color2']` before the loop. `$row['color1']` is not empty.

Comment: @nickb - your code doesn't exactly replicate what the OP's example is doing. If you look further down (and in var_dump), `$row['color1']` and `$row['color2']` are actually defined as `51A800` and `8FC400`, there's just a gap in the array indices.

Comment: Ah. I see it now. Perhaps there is some code inconsistency between what he's executing and what's posted here - The demo prints his `$colors` array just like he has above.

Comment: @mason81 - Look at my most recent edit, the answer is right in front of us! Array entry 72 is missing / gone, which explains your entire problem.

Comment: you went to extra long extend to try to solve this issue, I could vote up two times, I would ;)

Comment: @nickb Thanks for the update. I checked out your demos too. The problem is indeed that there is an empty index 72, but I don't know how it is being created as I am not doing anything else to the array other than what is in my code in the OP. I'm not removing, changing, or unsetting anything.

Comment: @roselan Indeed, nickb did go to quite an extent to help me solve this, and I do greatly appreciate that... of course I appreciate everyone else's efforts too, lol

Comment: @nickb I'm going to mark yours as the best answer. My code is working now after several changes... The changes you suggested as well as a few other suggestions from the comments. None of them really directly solved the null problem, but somehow together it seems to have made a difference. I appreciate your extra efforts. Also, I think worth adding is that a server-restart may be part of the solution as well. slugonamission mentioned it might be a bug in php and I restarted my server when this morning and then made some of the changes mentioned here, not sure if it made a difference or not.

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't it be:

```
..$i<sizeof($count)
```